# Python convert string into variable then use in function

Tags: python, arrays, function, type-conversion, generator

I've generated a variable names for pN from N=0 to n:

```
p0, p1, p2, p3, p4,....,pn
```

So far I got:

```
P = ['p0', 'p1', 'p2',..., 'pn']
```

What I want to do now is convert them into variable names to be called upon and used in a function. 
Convert 'p0' to p0, and so on for all of the values in

```
P = ['p0', 'p1', 'p2',..., 'pn']
```

So it becomes

```
P = [p0, p1, p2,..., pn]
```

Then generate functions using the variables:

```
Fi = P[i]/2
```

ie:

```
F0 = p0/2
F1 = p1/2
F2 = p2/2
```

Problem is I don't know how to convert 'pn' to pn properly, then generate functions based on pn. How do I do that? Or rather, what am I doing wrong?

Here's what I got:

```
# Define the constants
# ====================
k = 1
m = 1

# Generate the names
# ==================
n = 10 # Number of terms
P = [] # Array for momenta names
Q = [] # Array for positon names
for i in range (n): # Generate the names for
    p = "p"+str(i)  # momentum
    q = "q"+str(i)  # positon
    # Convert the names into variales
    exec("%s = %d" % p)
    exec("%s = %d" % q)
    # Put the names into the arrays
    P.append(p)
    Q.append(q)
# Print the names out for error checking
print(P)
print(Q)

# Generate the functions
# ======================
Q_dot = []

for i in range(n):
    def Q_dot(P[i]):
        q_dot = P[i] / m
        Q_dot.append(q_dot)
    i += 1
```

Note: I want to keep my variables as variables because I'm using the functions to solve a system of differential equations. My goal is to create a list of differential equations with the same format.

Comment: You should look into dictionaries. Not only is your current approach difficult to build and maintain but you do yourself no favours having all these variables floating around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: I did. The problem with that is that I have to assign a value to each of the variables, which I don't want to do because I'm using the variables to solve a differential equation.

Comment: Use a *container* like a list or a dict, don't use a bunch of variables with dynamic execution using `exec`. That's a really bad design

Comment: I don't think the items I create in a list are variable, since the function I created don't recognize them as variables whet it is called upon. What should I do to have them be recognized as variables?

Comment: YOU SHOULD put them into a dictionary as keys!